# Confused about virtual network interfaces needed for network

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, pfsense

I am relatively new to networking and have researched a lot about the topic however I am still confused as to what kind of virtual set-up I need.

I have linked a diagram of the network over here: [network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFr8j.png). All the machines except for pfSense are ubuntu 14.04.

The aim is to have all machines to be accessible from/to each other and to have access to the internet (via the switch). My understanding is that virtual_machine_0 and virtual_machine_1 have to be connected to a virtual bridge.

Where I am confused is how the pfSense machine fits into the picture? Is it connected to eth0 for WAN and then the bridge (which the virtual machines are connected to) for VLAN? Would all machines connected in such a way appear to be on the same network?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the pfSense VM?

Comment: I want to use pfSense as a firewall for the two virtual machines as they are the only accessible machines from the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a little challenging to answer as a newbie on the site prevents from asking via comment, but lets see if I can be of help:

For a start you will need two network interfaces in the pfSense VM. One for public which is connected to the switch and one for private which is connected to VM1 and VM2. This means in your VM Host you will need two networks or VLANS.

One bridged to the physical port of your VM Host (so it connects to the switch) and the other is within the VM Host.

VM1 and VM2 will each need one port.

Assuming you are using Xen as your hypervisor (VM Host software) on Ubuntu and you are following the instructions found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen, then at this page (http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Network_Configuration_Examples_(Xen_4.1%2B) you can use (in the ‘Example Debian-style bridge configuration (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu) section)

- Example 1 for the main (switch connected) NIC of the pfSense VM and then
- Example 4 for the second pfSense NIC and the VM1 and VM2 machine NIC’s.

You will need to configure pfSense to route what you need routed but that’s beyond this Q&A.